# Call another program's functions?

Tags: cocoa, macos, scripting

So I have this program that I really like, and it doesn't support Applescript. I'd like to automate it a little bit. Now, I know that I could use applescript to tell the program to tell the menu to tell the submenu to tell the menuitem to activate or whatever, but frankly I don't like applescript very much anyway.

When I open the NIB file in IB, I can see the messages that are being sent to FirstResponder; for example, the Copy menu item sends "`copy:`". Is there any way for me to invoke this directly from another program?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. It's called protected memory for a reason, you know. The other program is completely insulated from your application. There are ways to put code into other apps, but (a) it's very inadvisable (b) requires root privileges, which means the rest of your app needs to be ROCK SOLID AND IMPREGNABLE, and (c) writing such code is a black art requiring knowledge of the operating system kernel interfaces, virtual memory management, the ABI, the internals of the linker/loader, assembler programming, and the operational parameters and other specifics of the particular processor upon which your app happens to be running.

Really, AppleEvents and other such IPC mechanisms are there for a reason.

Your other alternatives (all of which are a bit hacky, to be honest, and give you the fairly significant burden of ensuring the target app is in the state you want/expect) the access the data you're looking for are:

1. The Accessibility APIs from the ApplicationServices framework, through which you can traverse the UI tree to grab the text from wherever you need it directly, or can activate the menu item. Access for your app has to be explicitly granted by the user, however (although this is much the same as the requirement for UI scripting).
2. You can use the CoreGraphics APIs (within the ApplicationServices framework again) to send keyboard events to the target application (or just to the system) directly. This would mean sending four events: Command-down, C-down, C-up, Command-up.

None of these are ideal. To be honest, your best approach would be to look at your requirements and figure out how you can best engineer around the problem by changing those requirements in some way, i.e. instead of grabbing something directly, ask the user to provide some input, etc.

Comment: Getting your code into another application on OS X does not (unfortunately or fortunately, depending on how you look at it) require most (if any) of the things you list there. For example most of the Safari hacks are input managers, or based on a third-party bootstrapping tools, so the authors don't have to know anything about assembly, kernel programming, etc.

Not to say that it isn't inadvisable--but it's not nearly that hard if you really want to go that route. And if this this is just a tool for personal use, stability/safety may not be a concern.

Comment: *shrugs*

Having done all of the above myself, and worked on command & control of the OS X operating system for some years, I figured I might as well put my oar in. Also, remember that Input Managers are going away fast, and they only affect Cocoa applications in the first place.

Comment: I'm not sure why this answer was voted down; in case it was because of my comment let me clarify: I wasn't disagreeing with the overall answer, just that specific aside. The answer to the question is definitely "No." If you want to call a method in an application (and it doesn't already have something like DO to allow IPC-based access), you must get code into that process.

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in [SIMBL](https://github.com/albertz/simbl) or in [mach_inject](https://github.com/rentzsch/mach_star). SIMBL is a daemon (in my fork based on mach_inject, in the original version based on injection via some ScriptingAdditions hack) which does the injection for you, so you just need to put a bundle with your code into the SIMBL directory and SIMBL will inject it for you into the target application. Or you can do so yourself via mach_inject. Or probably more convenient, mach_inject_framework which injects and runs code which just loads some framework.

Answer (score 0):

I think Jim may overstate the point a bit; he's not wrong, but it seems misleading. There are lots of ways to cause a Cocoa program to execute its own code under you control (Carbon is harder). The Accessibility API is very commonly used this way (so commonly that I expect it to be repurposed eventually). [Fscript](http://www.fscript.org) can give you all kinds of access to the innards of another Cocoa program. While Input Managers may well exit the scene at some point, [SIMBL](http://www.culater.net/software/SIMBL/SIMBL.php) is still out there today to do this kind of stuff.

Whether you like Applescript or not, Apple Events are the primary way Apple provides for inter-program control. Have you double-checked Script Editor's Open Library function to find out if the program really does have any Applescript support? You can code Apple Events entirely in Objective-C these days using Leopard's Scripting Bridge. I wrote up a [tutorial](http://robnapier.net/blog/scripting-bridge-265) if you like (it's still under-documented by Apple).

Cocoa is a reverse-engineer's dream. The same guys who host SIMBL have a nice [intro to the subject](http://www.culater.net/wiki/moin.cgi/CocoaReverseEngineering). ["Wolf"](http://redshed.net) also writes a lot of useful information on this.

Jim's right. Many of these approaches can completely destabilize the system if done incorrectly (sometimes even if done correctly). I don't do much of this stuff on my production systems; I need them to work. But there are a lot of things you can make a Mac app do, and it's a good part of a Mac developer's training to understand how all the pieces really work.

Comment: But the question was very specific: "Is there any way for me to invoke [arbitrary messages on an object] directly from another program?" Yes, there are things like Apple Events and DO that are designed for cross-process calling, and yes you can hack your code into their process, but there is no way to do specifically what was asked.